# Unable to extend the volume, the option is greyed out

Tags: windows, partition, diskmanagement

I'm trying to extend the D partition: with the new unallocated space, but it doesn't give me a choice, I've been looking at the Microsoft documentation and it indicates that it may be for these reasons:

- The unallocated space must be next to each other (Correct)
- Partitions must be in RAW or NTFW (Correct)
- As it is MBR, it should not reach 2tb Disk size (Nowhere near that)

It still won't let me extend this poartition, why?

[Disk Management scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGoxK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here](https://www.hdd-tool.com/disk-space-issue/extend-volume-greyed-out.html) is the explanation.

reason 4.

In GPT style disk, all partitions are created as Primary, but in MBR disk, there could be both Primary and Logical partition. Unlike Primary partitions that work as independent unit, Logical Partition is part of the Extended partition. Extended partition works like a container and the disk space of Logical partition will be converted to Free after deleting.

Free space deleted from Logical drive can't be extended to any Primary partition, Unallocated space deleted from Primary partition can't be extended to any Logical drive.

Comment: Okay, any option to extend that partition? I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Comment: sure, save files on external storage, remove logical partition... create full primary, move files back.. or try use doubtful software like easeus partition master.

Comment: As those are logical expanded volumes, you'd have to move the data and delete them. GPT is a lot more flexibe.